# Input function from user matplotlib in python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to make a program that can graph a function that the user write. The graph is from a parametric function.
I am using matplotlib in python but I can do that the user writes convert into the function that matplotlib uses.
Can you help me please? Or can you suggest me other python's library?
Here is my code and what I have tried:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
from numpy import *

go=False
inputX=raw_input("Write the function for X: ")
inputY=raw_input("Write the function for Y: ")
inputZ=raw_input("Write the function for Z: ")

if len(inputX)>0 and len(inputY)>0 and len(inputZ)>0:
  go=True

if go==True:
  mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

  t = linspace(-4 * pi, 4 * pi, 200)

  #I would like that the user input convert in the function for each "axis"
  z = t
  x = sin(t)
  y = cos(t)

  ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Test')

  ax.legend()
  plt.show()
```

In the first, I just checked the len of each input but when I tried to pass the input to the function matplotlib gives me an error, and is beacuse the user input is a string no the kind of the variable that is required.

Thank you for your help, and sorry about my english.

Comment: could you explain why do you have `if` condition for `x`,`y`,`z` while  they have been defined later?

Comment: Do you mean this: if len(inputX)>0 and len(inputY)>0 and len(inputZ)>0? This is because I just want to controll when show the graph. I thought that first ask for the equation, then give what the user wrote to que equation in matplotlib and after show the graph. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified [this pyparsing program](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py/30154950/fourFn.py), to accept `t` as a variable:

```
from pyparsing import Literal,CaselessLiteral,Word,Combine,Group,Optional,\
    ZeroOrMore,Forward,nums,alphas
from numpy import *
import operator

exprStack = []

def pushFirst( strg, loc, toks ):
    exprStack.append( toks[0] )
def pushUMinus( strg, loc, toks ):
    if toks and toks[0]=='-': 
        exprStack.append( 'unary -' )
        #~ exprStack.append( '-1' )
        #~ exprStack.append( '*' )

bnf = None
def BNF():
    """
    expop   :: '^'
    multop  :: '*' | '/'
    addop   :: '+' | '-'
    integer :: ['+' | '-'] '0'..'9'+
    atom    :: PI | E | real | T | fn '(' expr ')' | '(' expr ')'
    factor  :: atom [ expop factor ]*
    term    :: factor [ multop factor ]*
    expr    :: term [ addop term ]*
    """
    global bnf
    if not bnf:
        point = Literal( "." )
        e     = CaselessLiteral( "E" )
        fnumber = Combine( Word( "+-"+nums, nums ) + 
                           Optional( point + Optional( Word( nums ) ) ) +
                           Optional( e + Word( "+-"+nums, nums ) ) )
        ident = Word(alphas, alphas+nums+"_$")

        plus  = Literal( "+" )
        minus = Literal( "-" )
        mult  = Literal( "*" )
        div   = Literal( "/" )
        lpar  = Literal( "(" ).suppress()
        rpar  = Literal( ")" ).suppress()
        addop  = plus | minus
        multop = mult | div
        expop = Literal( "^" )
        pi    = CaselessLiteral( "PI" )
        t     = CaselessLiteral( "T" )

        expr = Forward()
        atom = (Optional("-") + ( pi | e | t | fnumber | ident + lpar + expr + rpar ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) | ( lpar + expr.suppress() + rpar )).setParseAction(pushUMinus) 

        # by defining exponentiation as "atom [ ^ factor ]..." instead of "atom [ ^ atom ]...", we get right-to-left exponents, instead of left-to-righ
        # that is, 2^3^2 = 2^(3^2), not (2^3)^2.
        factor = Forward()
        factor << atom + ZeroOrMore( ( expop + factor ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) )

        term = factor + ZeroOrMore( ( multop + factor ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) )
        expr << term + ZeroOrMore( ( addop + term ).setParseAction( pushFirst ) )
        bnf = expr
    return bnf

# map operator symbols to corresponding arithmetic operations
epsilon = 1e-12
opn = { "+" : operator.add,
        "-" : operator.sub,
        "*" : operator.mul,
        "/" : operator.truediv,
        "^" : operator.pow }
fn  = { "sin" : sin,
        "cos" : cos,
        "tan" : tan,
        "abs" : abs,
        "trunc" : lambda a: int(a),
        "round" : round,
        "sgn" : lambda a: abs(a)>epsilon and cmp(a,0) or 0}

def evaluateStack( s ):
    op = s.pop()
    if op == 'unary -':
        return -evaluateStack( s )
    if op in "+-*/^":
        op2 = evaluateStack( s )
        op1 = evaluateStack( s )
        return opn[op]( op1, op2 )
    elif op == "PI":
        return math.pi # 3.1415926535
    elif op == "E":
        return math.e  # 2.718281828
    elif op == "T":
        return linspace(-4 * pi, 4 * pi, 200)
    elif op in fn:
        return fn[op]( evaluateStack( s ) )
    elif op[0].isalpha():
        return 0
    else:
        return float( op )

def compute(s):   
    global exprStack
    exprStack = []
    results = BNF().parseString( s )
    val = evaluateStack( exprStack[:] )
    return val

fun=raw_input("Please input a function to be evaluated: ")
print compute(fun)
```

For example this program does the following:

```
Please input a function to be evaluated: 2+sin(t)
[ 2.          2.12595971  2.24991296  2.36988529  2.4839656   2.59033669
  2.68730414  2.77332333  2.84702403  2.90723225  2.95298891  2.98356514
  2.99847388  2.99747765  2.98059231  2.94808684  2.90047903  2.83852724
  2.7632183   2.67575185  2.57752115  2.47009096  2.35517255  2.2345965
  2.1102835   1.98421376  1.85839548  1.73483286  1.61549416  1.50228037
  1.39699489  1.30131485  1.21676437  1.14469026  1.08624063  1.04234653
  1.01370716  1.00077873  1.00376718  1.0226249   1.05705151  1.1064986
  1.17017854  1.24707694  1.33596886  1.43543832  1.54390084  1.6596287
  1.78077842  1.90542019  2.03156855  2.15721404  2.28035523  2.39903056
  2.51134962  2.61552324  2.70989202  2.79295273  2.86338228  2.92005876
  2.96207936  2.98877473  2.99971963  2.99473972  2.97391431  2.93757514
  2.88630108  2.82090888  2.74244018  2.65214495  2.55146151  2.44199369
  2.32548523  2.20379202  2.07885255  1.95265701  1.82721561  1.70452655
  1.58654417  1.47514784  1.37211203  1.27907802  1.19752779  1.12876036
  1.07387115  1.03373451  1.00898979  1.00003115  1.0070013   1.0297892
  1.06803187  1.12112012  1.1882083   1.26822773  1.35990378  1.46177609
  1.57222193  1.68948197  1.81168833  1.93689437  2.06310563  2.18831167
  2.31051803  2.42777807  2.53822391  2.64009622  2.73177227  2.8117917
  2.87887988  2.93196813  2.9702108   2.9929987   2.99996885  2.99101021
  2.96626549  2.92612885  2.87123964  2.80247221  2.72092198  2.62788797
  2.52485216  2.41345583  2.29547345  2.17278439  2.04734299  1.92114745
  1.79620798  1.67451477  1.55800631  1.44853849  1.34785505  1.25755982
  1.17909112  1.11369892  1.06242486  1.02608569  1.00526028  1.00028037
  1.01122527  1.03792064  1.07994124  1.13661772  1.20704727  1.29010798
  1.38447676  1.48865038  1.60096944  1.71964477  1.84278596  1.96843145
  2.09457981  2.21922158  2.3403713   2.45609916  2.56456168  2.66403114
  2.75292306  2.82982146  2.8935014   2.94294849  2.9773751   2.99623282
  2.99922127  2.98629284  2.95765347  2.91375937  2.85530974  2.78323563
  2.69868515  2.60300511  2.49771963  2.38450584  2.26516714  2.14160452
  2.01578624  1.8897165   1.7654035   1.64482745  1.52990904  1.42247885
  1.32424815  1.2367817   1.16147276  1.09952097  1.05191316  1.01940769
  1.00252235  1.00152612  1.01643486  1.04701109  1.09276775  1.15297597
  1.22667667  1.31269586  1.40966331  1.5160344   1.63011471  1.75008704
  1.87404029  2.        ]
```

So basically the `compute` function will evaluate simple expressions, and provide a linspace (var) if you use `t`. You can extend it, if you want. I think you can incorporate what you need from here to make your program work. :)